# YAML merge multiply anchors into the same map

Tags: yaml

It is not clear if it is possible to use [YAML merge key operator](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) several time for the same map.

The confusion comes from:

- **merge key** is only defined in outdated YAML 1.1 as an optional extension.
- there is no mentioning of it in https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html

Original spec says:

> The “<<” merge key is used to indicate that all the keys of one or more specified maps should be inserted into the current map.

but they don't provide an example and I cannot find it elsewhere. Like:

```yaml
defs:
- map1: &map1-ref
    key1: val1
- map2: &map2-ref
    key2: val2

config:
  database:
    <<: *map1-ref
    <<: *map2-ref
    key3: val3
```

Which major parsers support multiply merges (python/ruby/java/node)?

**UPDATE** Python 3 check code:

```py
import yaml
with open("my.yml") as f:
    y = yaml.safe_load(f)
    print(y)
```

**UPDATE 2** **@flyx**'s suggested syntax can be written in an alternative way:

```yaml
config:
  database:
    <<:
      - *map1-ref
      - *map2-ref
    key3: val3
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While a quick test shows that PyYAML does support this, I would advise against it since having multiple identical keys (`<<`) in the same mapping violates the core YAML spec (both 1.1 and 1.2).

Moreover, it is unnecessary since the merge key can take multiple maps as arguments:

```yaml
defs:
- map1: &map1-ref
    key1: val1
- map2: &map2-ref
    key2: val2

config:
  database:
    <<: [*map1-ref, *map2-ref]
    key3: val3
```

If you use this syntax, the question boils down to „which implementations support the merge key“. I can't give a full list but here's what I know:

- Supports it:

  - PyYAML
  - Java's SnakeYAML
  - Ruby's Psych
  - Perl's `YAML::PP`
  - go-yaml
- Does not support it:

  - yaml-cpp ([GH issue](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/pull/300))
  - libyaml (because its main interface is the event stream which is too low-level)
  - NimYAML (my work)
  - AdaYaml (my work)